# Android YouTubePlayerSupportFragment IllegalArgumentException crashes targetSdkVersion 23

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I have implemented YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in my android app.
For  targetSdkVersion=19, its working well.

But its crashing when I set targetSdkVersion 23.

Exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1209)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1308)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
```

Comment: Isn't it answer on your question - `Service Intent must be explicit:` ? Show place where you call `startActivity` or `startService`

Comment: use update api YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2 https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: @Divers : I have added YoutubeSupportFragment in StartActivity which is initialized through manifest entry..

Comment: @Exception Lover : yeah.. I am using 1.2.2, but facing same problem... code works with targetSdkVersion 19.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Youtube API

Its old Issue from youtube API.Download the latest version of the YouTube Android Player API [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/). Then build and Run your project.